# Second call of stored procedure throws ORA exception

Tags: c#, oracle, nhibernate, named-query

I am calling a stored procedure in an Oracle database via Nhibernate in my app. The first time I call it everything works fine and I get a result but the second time I get an ORA-00942 (table or view does not exist) exception. Any idea what could be possibly wrong?
The procedure just return me an object. No changes are done.
Thank you for your ideas.

Comment: Some example code might shed some more light on your problems. Just an error message is not a lot to work with.

Comment: So, you use Dynamic SQLs inside the procedure? Because if table is invalid, and no dynamic sql, then the proc itself could have been in INVALID state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have found out the mistake. It was a bad WCF config. It was missing  section because some guy deleted it. Thank you for your help.